# How do I use Nextjs Link tag along with data dismiss attribute?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, navigation, bootstrap-modal, next.js

Please I am working on a nextjs project. On mobile view my navigation uses a modal to toggle the navbar, but when I click on navigaton link only the data gets dismissed but the link doesn't navigate.

```html
<Link href="/market">
  <a className="nav-link" data-dismiss="modal">
    <span className="lay-outstyle">Market</span>
  </a>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<Link href="/market">
  <a className="nav-link" data-dismiss="modal">
    <span className="lay-outstyle">Market</span>
  </a>
</Link>
```

> Bind Link like this

```
<Link to="/market">
  <a className="nav-link" data-dismiss="modal">
    <span className="lay-outstyle">Market</span>
  </a>
</Link>
```

Comment: I tried but I get this error: 
(JSX attribute) to: string
Type '{ children: Element; to: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: any; children: any; }'.
  Property 'to' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: any; children: any; }'.

Comment: I am using next/link not react router link so it does not have the to attribute. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I fixed the issue. I used nextjs router (next/router) in an onClick function as shown below. Remember next js stores cache of route temporarily for fast access when you use the Link tag (same as react router)

```html
<Link href="/market">
  <a className="nav-link" onClick={() => router.push("/market")}>
    <span className="lay-outstyle">Members</span>
  </a>
</Link>
```